# Can I optimise a single linq query using 'Include' to eager load query elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a c# classes `Person` and `Note` which map to Sql Server tables and use with Entity Framework. In the `Person` data model `Note` is lazy loaded:

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int PersonType { get; set; }

    public int? NoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

When I query this using linq Is there any advantage to explicitly using Include at the beginning of my query? So is this:

```
personCount = myContext.Person.Include(p => p.Note).Count(
    m => m.PersonType == 3 &&
    (m.Note.Expires == null || m.Note.Expires > DateTime.Now))
```

More efficient than this:

```
personCount = myContext.Person.Count(
    m => m.PersonType == 3 &&
    (m.Note.Expires == null || m.Note.Expires > DateTime.Now))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is no benefit to using `Include`.

Include is used to ensure associated linked entity types are eagerly loaded (rather than the default lazy loading). This avoids lots of requests to load each referenced instance (eg. when iterating through a collection).

But you are not returning any entity types here. So eager or lazy loading is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought but a colleague assures me he has seen instances where more than one sql query was executed when the 'include' was omitted. He says we should always explicitly use 'include' just in case so I thought I'd ask here. Perhaps he saw that with a more complex query or an older version of ef?

Comment: @jonaglon That many queries case is where you iterate over a set of results looking at a lazy loaded property and see an additional query each time around the loop (thus getting 1+n queries).